# Scripts for computing the average of a list of numbers in a data file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

The file `data.txt` contains the following:

```
1.00 1.23 54.4 213.2 3.4
```

The output of the scripts are supposed to be:

```
ave: 54.646
```

Some simple scripts are preferred.

Comment: what if you have multiple lines?

Comment: awk '{s+=$1}END{print "ave:",s/NR}' RS="\n" file #if you have one record per line

Comment: the default record separator(RS) is \n so you don't need to specify RS="\n" if you have multiple lines. `awk '{s+=$1}END{print "ave:",s/NR}' file`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
$ awk '{s+=$1}END{print "ave:",s/NR}' RS=" " file
ave: 54.646
```

Comment: That will produce a division by zero error on an empty file. You need something like `awk '{s+=$1}END{print "ave:",(NR?s/NR:"NaN")}' RS=" " file`

Comment: As someone new to awk, I run this on this list: 8.20
7.10
8.10
7.40
6.50
8.40
7.90
8.50
9.30
8.80
9.80
9.50
8.20
9.20
8.30
9.10 and get an average of 8.2. If I sum the values, awk '{s+=$1}END{print "sum:" s}'  I get 134.3. Divide this by the number of values and you get 8.39... which matches calculating it by spreadsheet. Does awk reduce the number of significant figures?

Answer (score 55):

Another option is to use `jq`:

```
$ seq 100|jq -s add/length
50.5
```

`-s` (`--slurp`) creates an array for the input lines after parsing each line as JSON, or as a number in this case.

Edit: `awk` is faster and it doesn't require reading the whole input to memory:

```
$ time seq 1e6|awk '{x+=$0}END{print x/NR}'>/dev/null

real  0m0.145s
user  0m0.148s
sys   0m0.008s
$ time seq 1e6|jq -s add/length>/dev/null

real  0m0.685s
user  0m0.669s
sys   0m0.024s
```

Comment: probably one of the most creative ways to use `jq` i've seen!

Comment: this has the advantage of being able to be used after having used jq to filter out the necessary numbers, like: ` jq -r '.SpotPriceHistory[].SpotPrice' | jq -s add/length`

Comment: FYI if you're averaging a lot of numbers. This is definitely way slower than the awk method. I can't be bothered to benchmark it, but for 14 million integers, `awk` returns nearly instantly while the `jq` method takes awhile...

Comment: Yeah although this is super neat and although it's not *that* slow, this is indeed pretty slow, only suitable for processing very small datasets.

Comment: @nisetama I had a billion lines or so to work with, other solutions finished, jq's didn't because I gave up on it :)

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -lane '$a+=$_ for(@F);print "ave: ".$a/scalar(@F)' file
```

if you have multiple lines and you just need a single average:

```
perl -lane '$a+=$_ for(@F);$f+=scalar(@F);END{print "ave: ".$a/$f}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the **average** (time took for each ping request)

```
ping -c 5 www.youtube.com | grep time= | awk -F '[= ]' '{ sum += $11 } END { printf("%.2f ms\n", sum/NR) }'
```

- `-c` in `ping` request is for numbers of `icmp` requests to send.
- `-F` in `grep` used to specify the field separators.
- We can use `printf` to control number of **precision** we want to display after the decimal points in our case it is 2 decimal points(`%.2f`).
- “`NR`” is a special built-in variable of `AWK` that stands for "**number of records**". This variable is used to deal with the number of records present in the specified files.
- We are calculating **average** by diving `sum` with `NR`

---

You can also find the `sum` (sum of all time took by the ping request)

```
ping -c 5 www.youtube.com | grep time= | awk -F '[= ]' '{ sum += $11 } END { printf("%.2f ms\n", sum) }'
```