# Find average of numbers from a specific line

Tags: awk, average

I have a text file with 2 columns of numbers.

```
10 2
20 3
30 4
40 5 
50 6
60 7 
70 8 
80 9
90 10
100 11
110 12
120 13
130 14
```

I would like to find the **average of the 2nd column data from the 6th line**. That is ( (7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14)/8 = 10.5 )

I could find this post [Scripts for computing the average of a list of numbers in a data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681498/scripts-for-computing-the-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in-a-data-file)
and used the following:

`awk'{s+=$2}END{print "ave:",s/NR}' fileName`

but I get an average of entire second column data.

Any hint here.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results (or errors) you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I do personally think my example is explained clear enough. I tried the snippet available in the mentioned post. But its here for you. awk'{s+=$2}END{print "ave:",s/NR}' fileName

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri: Can you create an actual file with 15+ lines and show us what do you want out of it?

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri, your question still includes no code, and the question you've linked to has a number of answers. If YOU have made an attempt, that attempt should be included in your question.

Comment: @Inian .. I don't think it's wrong, he said *"from the 6th line"*, not *"after"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner should do:

```
awk -v s=6 'NR<s{next} {c++; t+=$2} END{printf "%.2f (%d samples)\n", t/c, c}' file
```

This awk script has three pattern/action pairs. The first is responsible for skipping the first `s` lines. The second executes on every line (from `s` onwards); it increments a counter and adds column 2 to a running total. The third runs after all data have been processed, and prints your results.

Comment: `NR<s{next} {c++; t+=$2}` = `NR>=s{c++; t+=$2}`. Also, just tweak `t/c` to `(c?t/c:0)` or similar to prevent a divide by zero error when there's fewer than `s` lines in the input file.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's true, your suggestion is functionally equivalent. It also seems to be slightly faster in gawk. In BSD awk, however, your solution is about 5% slower. Nice that there are so many ways to solve problems. ;-) Also, re the divide-by-zero, that's a great point. I won't add it to my answer though, because the average of no samples is undefined (or, a legitimate error), not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Below script should do the job

```
awk 'NR>=6{avg+=$2}END{printf "Average of field 2 starting from 6th line %.1f\n",avg/(NR-5)}' file
```

**Output**

```
Average of field 2 starting from 6th line 10.5
```